# What is the correct logic for the output which i am getting for sample threading code

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my sample threading code.

```
public class Deadlock {
    static class Friend {
        private final String name;
        public Friend(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public synchronized void bow(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
                + "  has bowed to me!%n", 
                this.name, bower.getName());
            synchronized(bower) { //this is the change
                 bower.bowBack(bower);
            }

        }
        public  void bowBack(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
                + " has bowed back to me!%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Friend alphonse =
            new Friend("Alphonse");
        final Friend gaston =
            new Friend("Gaston");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { alphonse.bow(gaston); }
        }).start();
//       Thread.sleep(20);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

This would go into a deadlock.
But If I make a small change in it. Instead of using 'bower' as the monitor for synchronized block, I use 'this', It does not go into deadlock.

```
  public class Deadlock {
    static class Friend {
        private final String name;
        public Friend(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }
        public synchronized void bow(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
                + "  has bowed to me!%n", 
                this.name, bower.getName());
            synchronized(this) { //This is the change.
                 bower.bowBack(bower);
            }

        }
        public  void bowBack(Friend bower) {
            System.out.format("%s: %s"
                + " has bowed back to me!%n",
                this.name, bower.getName());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        final Friend alphonse =
            new Friend("Alphonse");
        final Friend gaston =
            new Friend("Gaston");
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { alphonse.bow(gaston); }
        }).start();
//       Thread.sleep(20);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() { gaston.bow(alphonse); }
        }).start();
    }
   }
```

Please help me in getting the correct reason behind the behaviour showed by above piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that

```
synchronized(objectidentifier) {
   // Access shared variables and other shared resources
}
```

Here, the objectidentifier is a reference to an object whose lock associates with the monitor that the synchronized statement represents.

synchronized(bower) uses the Monitor from bower and it is a different object.
You make a lock for bower. Because both threads lock the objects in another thread the deadlock happens.

And synchronized(this) uses the own monitor. You make a lock for the own objects. The threads lock the objects in the same threads and nobody cares.

Please correct me if I'm wrong!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my confusion. +1.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is that while bowing to somebody you can not bow back.

I would add `synchronized` to the `bowBack` method and remove `synchronize(this)` or `synchronize(bower)` from `bow...()`

Comment: your approach would lead to a deadlock. which is similar to my first piece of code, where i used synchronized(bower) in bow().